# How do I specify the MATLAB editor keybindings programmatically

Tags: matlab, scripting

I want to setup the keyboard keybindings as *Windows Default Set* and I would like to do this at startup using the `startup.m` because I want this setting to be set on a large number of systems.

The equivalent setting in the preferences dialog is: `MATLAB > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Active Settings: Windows Default Set.`

### Proposal of `startup.m` after Suever's answer

See line 8

```
% TODO set startup script in $HOME/Documents/bin/matlab/startup.m in Terminal

% all commands here will be run at startup etc startup.m
% TODO set user path as relative by $HOME/Documents/bin/matlab/
%userpath('/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/')
% TODO How to set up userpath outside this Matlab script in Terminal?

% http://stackoverflow.com/a/38188945/54964
if ( not( com.mathworks.services.Prefs.getStringPref('CurrentKeyBindingSet') == 'Windows' ) )
        com.mathworks.services.Prefs.setStringPref('CurrentKeyBindingSet', 'WindowsDefaultSet.xml')
end

% Event errors else with touchpad scroll
!synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
```

Matlab: 2016a
System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this programmatically you can do it using the [undocumented](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-system-preferences-programmatically) functions for setting the preferences.

```
com.mathworks.services.Prefs.setStringPref('CurrentKeyBindingSet', 'Windows')
```

If you want a different keybinding, you can set the value explicitly from the preferences dialog and then call the following to retrieve the value.

```
com.mathworks.services.Prefs.getStringPref('CurrentKeyBindingSet')
```

This command should only have to be run once per MATLAB installation so placing it within the `startup.m` file may be overkill and would also prevent users from being able to change your default settings.

Comment: @Masi MATLAB will automatically run `startup.m` if it's placed within the `userpath` or the current working directory.

Comment: @Masi what? `userpath` is just the default user folder. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/userpath.html

Comment: @Masi It doesn't require the GUI.... also you only need to run the above command *once* per system so it doesn't really need to be in `startup.m`

Comment: @Masi as far as I know you can't. You can check the current value with the second command

Comment: @Masi You don't really gain anything by that `if` though. Just set it. Also I believe you can just set it to `'Windows'` as I've shown above.

Comment: Also setting the `userpath` from within `startup.m` really has no effect since MATLAB already looks in `userpath` for the file. Anyhow that's really another question completely. This question appears to be solved.

Comment: @Masi Right but it's probably easier just to *always* set it regardless of what it is, because if it's different you're going to change it anyhow

Comment: Continua is here about setting `userpath` in Terminal http://stackoverflow.com/q/38191001/54964 I cannot find about it in Docs.