# How to Set up Matlab's userpath in Terminal?

Tags: matlab, scripting

I want to set Matlab's `userpath` etc the following in Terminal, instead of doing it in GUI Matlab session.

```
userpath('/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/')
```

This thread is continua 2 of the thread [How do I specify the MATLAB editor keybindings programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38188831/54964)
 about `startup.m` where I can set some other things. 
I cannot find about it in Documentation so it must be in the undocumented part of Matlab because I know this feature can be done.

### My proposal after Suever's answer

Run just once after the installation

```
echo "export MATLAB_USE_USERWORK=1" >> $HOME/.bashrc

matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r \ 
    "userpath('/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/'); exit;"
```

### Problem with `userpath` and `addpath`

See test codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38283814/54964). Some other configurations have to be applied too.

Matlab: 2016a
System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You do realize you can run MATLAB from the command line without a GUI right? `matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r 'userpath(blah)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, the `startup.m` file should be located within the folder in which you were when you launched MATLAB from the command line.

> On Linux® platforms, the default startup folder is the folder from which you started MATLAB.

If you want to use `userpath` as the startup folder instead of the current directory, you can specify that you'd like to use the `userpath` via the environment variable `MATLAB_USE_USERWORK=1`. This will by default point it at `$HOME/Documents/MATLAB` (or an alternate location if that was set within MATLAB).

> To specify the userpath as the startup folder, set the value of the environment variable MATLAB_USE_USERWORK to 1 before startup. By default, userpath is userhome/Documents/MATLAB, and MATLAB automatically adds the userpath folder to the top of the search path upon startup. To specify a different folder for userpath, and for other options, use the MATLAB userpath function.

More info in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/matlab-startup-folder.html)

As a side note, if you need to run a MATLAB command from the terminal, it is possible to run MATLAB without the UI and have it execute the necessary command.

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r 'commands_here; exit;'
```

Comment: What do you actually need to run that's in two places? This is completely separate from `PATH`

Comment: You can use `MATLAB_USE_USERWORK=1` environment variable to tell MATLAB to use the userpath instead of the current directory.

Comment: @Masi Look closely at the name of the environment variable. Looks like you used `_USER_` instead of `_USE_`

Comment: @Masi You can also read the documentation for yourself to avoid confusion. It's quite helpful.